# Get data from two tables using by data from another table in SQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have got 3 tables on my database. Lets assume they are named as ACC, POS, CON.

At ACC table i have got ID and NAME columns. At POS table, there is LAT and LONG columns and at CON table, AccID and FrID columns.

to give an example.

```
                      ACC          /          POS         /     CON
                ID         NAME   / ID   LAT     LONG    / AccID     FrID
                1          Mike      1    10       15       1         2
                2          Bob       2    20       25       1         4             
                3          Jack      3    18       21       2         3            
                4          Rocky     4    37       45       2         1
```

This is the data from my 3 tables. Now i want to select all LAT and LONG values from POS and NAME values from NAME where AccID in FrID.

To be more specific, i want to check for Mike's friend's Lat Long. At Con table there is two friends of Mike, ID=2 and ID=4 so i want to get a table like.

```
ACC_NAME  LAT     LONG
Bob       20      25
Rocky     37      45
```

can you give me a query example for this problem. Thank you.

Comment: This is accomplished using two `INNER JOIN`'s. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am a newbie on db. I just tried to get data by using IN operator but it wasn't enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try by using `INNER JOIN`. Here is full Query:-

```
SELECT ACC.Name, POS.LAT, POS.LONG FROM CON
INNER JOIN ACC ON CON.FrID = ACC.ID
INNER JOIN POS ON POS.ID = ACC.ID
WHERE CON.AccID = 1
```

**Explanation Here**

1. Get All friends of Mike By

   `SELECT * FROM CON
    WHERE CON.AccID = 1 -- Mike Account Id`
2. Get Friends Name by Join with Acc Table

   `SELECT ACC.Name FROM CON
    INNER JOIN ACC ON CON.FrID = ACC.ID
    WHERE CON.AccID = 1`
3. Get Lat ang Long by Join with POS Table

   `SELECT ACC.Name, POS.LAT, POS.LONG FROM CON
    INNER JOIN ACC ON CON.FrID = ACC.ID
    INNER JOIN POS ON POS.ID = ACC.ID
    WHERE CON.AccID = 1`

Comment: Solved my problem. Thank you very much!!